# Как перемножить число с точкой и число с запятой?

Tags: excel, vba, типы

Есть `excel` документ в котором в ячейках хранятся числа с плавающей запятой. Я пытаюсь их считать но мне выдается ошибка "Несовпадение типов":

> "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

Для примера в ячейках следующие данные:

```
A1: 1,00    B1: 25,17
A2: 3,00    B2: 133.67
```

Пытаюсь считать эти числа так:

```
Dim Count        As Double
Dim Cost         As Double
Dim Summ         As Double

For i = 1 To LastRowOpenDbfSheet (Цикл с первой до последней строки в документе)
    Count = sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12)        // Так не работает
    Count = sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12).Value  // Так не работает
    Count = CDbl(sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12))  // Так не работает
```

Потом эти числа Count, Cost нужно перемножить. Какой правильно тип данных нужно указать и как считывать значения в ячейках что бы это заработало и можно было потом перемножать числа?

Comment: `StrCount, StrCost`  - где такое в Вашем описании? `Set` - присвоение переменной объекта. Зачем оно Вам? В `В2` значение с точкой - так и есть?

Comment: @vikttur поправил описание, на скорую руку просто писал, извиняюсь. В B2 значение с точкой. Вообще значение с точкой может быть в любом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Число" с точкой - текст, при математических операциях с такими данными будет ошибка. Нужно привести данные к единому типу.

```
Sub Sum_()
Dim aData()
Dim dSum As Double
Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' если нужно, указать другой лист'
        i = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        aData = .Range("A1:B" & i).Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            aData(i, 1) = Replace(aData(i, 1), ".", ",")
            aData(i, 2) = Replace(aData(i, 2), ".", ",")
            dSum = dSum + aData(i, 1) * aData(i, 2)
        Next i

        .Cells(1, 3).Value = dSum
    End With
End Sub
```

Правильнее данные хранить в одиаковых форматах.

Выделить диапазон данных, `Ctrl+H`, *НАЙТИ* точку, *ЗАМЕНИТЬ* на запятую, *ОК*.

С нормальными данными и макрос не нужен:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(A1:A100;B1:B100)
```

Answer (score 0):

При работе с базовыми типами (числами, строками и пр.), т.е. при присвоении значений, set не используется. Set нужен для присвоения идентификатора объекту класса.
Т.е. в Вашем случае будет:

```
Dim Count As Double  
Dim Cost As Double  
Dim Summ As Double
Dim i as integer

For i = 1 To LastRowOpenDbfSheet
   Count = sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12)        
   Count = sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12).Value  
   Count = CDbl(sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12))  
Next i
```